# Loading two images at a time in a loop using Python-glob

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to read all images from a folder using Python-glob. 
Here is the part of code:

> ```
>     for file in glob.glob("\*.jpg"):
>         image=cv2.imread(file);
> ```
>
> It is working pretty well, but I need to to read two images at a time in one iteration of the glob loop  i.e. the two consecutive images. In simple terms i need `image[i]` and `image[i+1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
files = glob.glob("\*.jpg")
img_a = cv2.imread(files[0])

for file in files[1:]:

    img_b = cv2.imread(file);

    # do what you need to do with img_a and img_b

    # and then prepare img_a for the next loop
    img_a = img_b
```

Comment: Thank you so much . So simple and intelligent approach.

Comment: In the last line is it necessary to do copy.copy? I mean simple img_a=img_b; will also work ?

Comment: If you only assign `img_a=img_b`, `img_a` will point to the same array as `img_b`, so as soon as you read a new `img_b` in the next loop, `img_a` will also be updated. Maybe you could try it out and see how it behaves, but I do think you need to explicitly copy the object.

Comment: @Lisa You don't need to copy.  Yes `img_a` will be the same object as `img_b` but `imread()` creates a new object that will be bound to the name `img_b`. Assigning to a name will have no effect on any object that was bound to that name before. (Except it may be fair game to the garbage collection if it isn't referenced anymore.)

Comment: @BlackJack Oh ok, good to know - thanks! I updated the answer accordingly.